# Cocos2d-x Where will be the best place to cache sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

I want to cache some sprite frames while the user sees a loading page.
When should I implement the following three things?

- display loading screen
- cache sprites
- hide loading screen

The choices are:

```
FirstScene : init
FirstScene : onEnter
FirstScene : onEnterTransitionDidFinish

... Move to the second scene ...

SecondScene : init
FirstScene : onExitTransitionStart
FirstScene : onExit
FirstScene : dealloc
SecondScene : onEnter
SecondScene : onEnterTransitionDidFinish

... Exit second scene ... 

SecondScene : onExitTransitionDidStart
SecondScene : onExit
SecondScene : dealloc
```

Comment: Using `CCSpriteFrameCache`?

Comment: Yea. using either "SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile()" or "SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFrame()"